# adding .className to object is not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to set a className to my nav element and it isn't working as intended. When I manually add the class to my HTML it puts a border around the unordered list items and the buttons. When I use js to add it, it shows that the nav tag has the attribute in the inspector but it does not add the border so I do not believe it is working. What am I doing wrong? I have linked to the bootstrap cdn and jquery cdn in the file.

```
HTML
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en-us">
    <head>
      <title>Exercise 5.9</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    </head>
    <body id="content">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <nav>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Our Policies</li>
          <li>How you can help</li>
          <li>What we have accomplished</li>
          <button type="button">Donate $10.00</button>
          <button type="button">Donate $50.00</button>
          <button type="button">Donate $100.00</button>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
        <p>If you would to offer financial support, please choose the buttons above</p>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="exercise-5.9.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

JS
var nav = document.getElementsByTagName("nav");
nav.className = "navbar navbar-default";
console.log(nav);
```

Comment: are you just trying to set the class name?

Comment: Try `var nav = document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0];` Since you want to get the first nav element.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an array of nodes.

Comment: I don't get you.. If you did `console.log(nav);`, why didn't you notice it's type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `.className =` try just setting the attribute of `class` to whatever you want. The main reason why it's not working, however, is because `.getElementsByTagName()` returns an array (nodeList) so you need to make sure when you set the class, it's properly indexed.

**Using `.setAttribute("atr", "value")`**

```
var button = document.getElementById("btnGo");

button.onclick = function () {
    var nav = document.getElementsByTagName("nav");

    for (var i = 0; i < nav.length; i++) {
        nav[i].setAttribute("class", "myClassName");
    }

};
```

**Using `.className`**

```
var button = document.getElementById("btnGo");

button.onclick = function () {
    var nav = document.getElementsByTagName("nav");

    for (var i = 0; i < nav.length; i++) {
        nav[i].className = "myClass";
    }

};
```

Comment: I think you may have misread the source code `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: Why suggest *setAttribute* instead of the *className* property? There is no benefit to that.

Comment: Something to also note here is that if you have element with multiple classes, `.setAttribute` and `.className` will both completely reset the class to the value that's passed. With that being said, there may be some unwanted behavior if you accidently overwrite a class. Writing something similar to (or even leveraging) jQuerys `.addClass` and `.removeClass` is a far better approach.

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByTagName() return an array, you should write `document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0];`

Comment: Not an array, a [*NodeList*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177).